# Excel Cell function

Tags: excel, function

I have this problem:

I have numbers in a column and want to color them in a function according to the number of the cell above each one.
If the number is larger then the numbers must be green, if it is smaller then red.

[image]

Like this table, 1 is smaller than 2, then 1 is red, then 433 is bigger than 1 then 433 must be green... all down the same.

Comment: I tried lots of things before but I didn't have good results since all the examples that i found are from cell values ​​of different columns but from the same row.

Comment: @DamianSIlvera - it looks like you have your answer already, but I think the DVs may be because you have not explained *in your question* what you've tried. As is, your question seems to be a "give me the solution" request... and those are frowned upon.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for answering my comments, I had not used the site for a while and the truth is that I am a bit out of knowledge of what it is used to put in the questions. I apologize if someone took it badly and put the negative points, I only had the problem and I planted it here because maybe someone could help.

Comment: Gotcha. [Relevant link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Create 2 rules on cell `A2` by navigating to `Home > Conditional Formatting`

- Rule 1: Select `Greater Than`, Input box `= A1`, Choose format
- Rule 2: Select `Less Than`, Input box `= A1`, Choose format
- Use the format painter to apply the rule all the way down your range

---

When putting in the cell reference, it's imortant to make sure the locked reference is turned off. I.E., you will get the wrong result if you were to input `= $A$1`

---

*unclear what happens with A1 or when the cells are equal*